# What's the difference between 'function foo (callback)' and 'foo(arg1, arg2, function(err,data))'?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I am a beginner to nodejs. I have downloaded the `learnyounode` module from [nodeschool.io](http://nodeschool.io/) and I am trying to do the `Make it modular` exercise from it. At the end of the exercise they have mentioned this:

> Also keep in mind that it is idiomatic to check for errors and do
>   early-returns within callback functions:
>
> ```
> function bar (callback) {
>   foo(function (err, data) {
>     if (err)
>       return callback(err) // early return
>
>     // ... no error, continue doing cool things with `data`
>
>     // all went well, call callback with `null` for the error argument
>
>     callback(null, data)
>   })
> }
> ```

Whenever I have tried to understand `callback` functions they were of the form:

```
foo(arg1, arg2, function(err,data){
    if(err)
        //Handle it
    //Do something with data
});
```

I am having a hard time understanding the difference between the two. I google-d for it, but honestly, there were some pages explaining the first callback style while there are some pages explaining the second one. I know that in the second style the `function(err, data)` is called asynchronously. My understanding by "asynchronously" is that `foo` is called with arg1 and arg2. When "foo" is completed `function(err,data)` is called.

However I don't get the `function bar (callback)` notation. Both of them are doing callbacks then what's the difference between them? Which notation should I use to solve my problem exercise? How do you decide which one to use and when?

Comment: To answer the question in the title, *"What's the difference between `function foo (callback)` and `foo(arg1, arg2, function(err,data))`?"*. The first one is a function **definition**, the second is a function **call**. They are and do  two completely different things. Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions to learn more about functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `foo(arg1, arg2, function(err,data){` You are calling `foo` and passing it a callback function as one of the parameters. In `function foo(callback)` you are *defining* foo and saying that its parameter is a function that you will refer to as "callback".

In a non-async setting you would write something like

```
//define foo
function foo(arg1, arg2){
    var someData = //...
    return someData;
}

//use foo
var data = foo(1, 2);
console.log(data);
```

In an async setting, functions call callbacks instead of returning values

```
//define foo
function fooAsync(arg1, arg2, callback){
    var someData = //...
    callback(someData);
}
```

and instead of assigning the return value to a variable, we pass a callback where that variable is a parameter:

```
//use foo
fooAsync(1, 2, function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

We can also pass named functions as callbacks. Passing an anonymous function is just the common case:

```
function processData(data){
    console.log(data);
}

fooAsync(1, 2, processData);
```